# PHP mysql Call to undefined method

Tags: php, mysql

Currently i'm having this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method users::prepare() in C:\xampp\htdocs\hrm2\header.php on line 21

dbconfig:

```
  <?php
class database{
function __construct()
{
    $db_user="root";
    $db_pass="";
    try {
        $con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=hrm', $db_user, $db_pass);
        $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        return $con;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
}
```

class.user.php

```
 <?php

 session_start();

class users
  {

   protected $db;

   function __construct(){

   require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/hrm2/dbconfig.php";
   $this->db= new database();

     }

    function select($userid){
       try{
          $stmt=$this->db->prepare("SELECT * from users where 
  uesrid=:userid");
       $stmt->execute(array(':userid'=>$userid));
      } catch(PDOException $e){
         $e->getMessage();
      }
  }
```

header.php, where the error is occuring:

```
    <!doctype html>


<?php

include('Class/class.user.php');


$user= new users();



// check if user is logged in
if($user -> logado()==""){
    $user->redirect('login.php');

}


 $userid=$_SESSION["sessao"];
$userRow=$user->select($userid);



?>
```

Seems like i'ts something about the prepare that i have on header.php file, which i don't know why it's working, i'm new as well on PHP OOP, so i think it can be a small mistake made from me.

Comment: You have no `prepare` method in your `users` class. What do you expect `$user->prepare()` to do? The return value of a constructor is ignored, it always returns an object of the class you're creating. You need to define a method that returns `$db`.

Comment: updated the code @Barmar

Comment: Why are you declaring a class inside of another class? Try including the file at the top and then instantiate the DB class inside of your users class.

Comment: @aynber Where ? I just included the DB inside the user, to make the connection to mysql

Comment: You have a typo in the query: `uesrid` should be `userid`

Comment: `user::select()` doesn't have a `return` statement. It also never calls `$stmt->fetch()`.

Comment: `logado()` where's that method? and `redirect()`? and was the session started?

Comment: The reason is working now is because you're using the `$db` property to prepare and execute the query. Since `$db` is an instance of `PDO` the `prepare` and `execute` functions work without problems.

Comment: The way I think of require/include is  adding the code in place. So take all of your code from the file you're including and drop it where you call your require function. Your code doesn't make sense where it is. Add your require_once to the top of the file instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`user::select()` is missing several things.

It doesn't call `$stmt->fetch()`, and it doesn't return anything. And when it catches an error, it doesn't print the error message. It also has a typo in the query.

```
function select($userid){
    try{
        $stmt=$this->db->prepare("SELECT * from users where userid=:userid");
        $stmt->execute(array(':userid'=>$userid));
        return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: *"It also has a typo in the query"* - I'd of worded it more like *"It also has a potential typo in the query"*. We can't be 100% sure of the schema.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, the error dissapeared, but appeared another one, but probably i need to make a new question, or can i ask here?

Comment: @Fred-ii- True, I've seen all sorts of misspellings in schemas, but I decided to go out on a limb here.

Comment: @sygamers Yes, probably best to post a new question.